# How can I write a paper that will convince the reviewers that the results are non-trivial?

Tags: writing

I submitted a paper in math/cs/economics to a top-level journal. The paper involves a new variant of a well-known problem. All reviewers agreed that the results are interesting and non-trivial, but they rejected the paper as not being general enough for their journal.

Encouraged by the positive feedback, I submitted an improved version of the paper to a medium-level conference. The improvements include simplifications of some of the proofs and additions of stronger results about the same problem. Now the reviewers rejected the paper claiming that the results are too weak and unsurprising!

What should I do in the next time I submit (to a different journal), in order to make the reviewers believe that the results are indeed surprising and non-trivial? I don't want to write the proofs in their more complicated version, as in the first revision, because this is unscientific. But writing it in a simple way seems that doing so creates a false impression that the results are too simple. What do you suggest?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to convince the reviewers that the results were **difficult**?  I think the word you're really looking for is **significant** or perhaps **surprising**.

Comment: @JeffE - Or the results were difficult **to attain**. I wonder if _difficult_ here is intended as a synonym for "not trivial."

Comment: Sorry, I still think this one is a dup. After reading both questions, I have a thought. If you can write this question to distinguish it from the other question, you can write your paper to convey why yours is not too weak and unsurprising. I think the answers to the other one (including yours) did not really solve the problem. The answers just told you why it is a difficult task.

Comment: @J.R. No. If the results are significant, it doesn't matter how hard they were to attain.  On the other hand, if the results are not significant, it doesn't matter how hard they were to attain.

Comment: @JeffE This is what I thought, but the reviewers probably thought differently...

Comment: @JeffE: The "significance" of a result is often subjective and/or difficult to evaluate.  To perform this evaluation, it's natural to take into account the "depth" or "difficulty" of the arguments.  If when refereeing a paper you meet a result that you had never thought to establish, it is very natural to stop and see if *you* know how to establish it, or have a sense of what would be needed to establish it.  You are also of course looking for "new ideas" and "new techniques", but it's a similar story; such things are much more convincing when there is no other easy way to solve the problem.

Comment: That said, I take the point that difficulty ought not to be valuable for its own sake.  In my experience, prestigious journals can lean too heavily on wanting to publish things that look hard and/or showcase exceptional technical skill (versus a more novel approach that doesn't look as hard).  My very first referee report, a rejection, contained the passage: "Admittedly, Theorem X is a nice result.  The proof, however, is not overly cumbersome."  To which I always react: "Wait!  Give me another chance: I can make the proof *much* harder."

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: And now, with a lot more experience gained after your first paper, do you see any way out of such situation for papers in mathematics (other than going to a lower-rank journal or making the proofs to appear complicated)?

Comment: @just-learning: For this first paper I submitted, the passage I quoted was weird but the verdict itself was reasonable.  In fact, I look back at the experience of not having a published (solo) paper that was written while I was still a student as an overall positive one: the paper was not as strong or mature as other papers I've written (and there were some problems with it, though the referee didn't catch them).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Thanks, I see your point. But what if the result is indeed important (as confirmed by some colleagues, not just the authors, but alas these colleagues are not editors in the top journals to whom one could submit the paper) but straightforward to state? And the proof is easy too (the idea uses a simple formalism, just from a slightly different area), so it all looks obvious to experts *after they see it* (but somehow this was not discovered for >20 years). In your opinion, is there any way to get such a paper into a really good *math* journal? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @just-learning: first, I thought I had a followup to my last comment, but I remember now that I didn't get around to posting it.  I certainly have no magic wand for getting papers accepted by really good math journals: I have written over 30 papers, none of which have been accepted by what I would call a *really good math journal*!  But what is probably my best publication -- it is in Crelle -- is my shortest (non-MAA type) paper and I am proud of how easy the proofs are.  The trick was: I answered a 50 year-old question of Lang and Tate.

Comment: Maybe that's a moral if you are truly "just learning" (including some information about yourself on your profile would help me target my responses, BTW): there are serious, professional research mathematicians like me who never even submit papers to the very top journals.  It doesn't mean that my work which is published in, say, the Journal of Number Theory is not "important".  It just means that it is not the world champion of impressive mathematical work.  If you're just starting out, it's more important that your work get published in *reputable* journals than fail to appear in top ones.

Comment: As a general rule, if you're solving a problem that no one had pointed out before and your proof uses only existing tools and doesn't have a feature that can be pointed to as especially hard or tricky: yes, I think it will be difficult or impossible to publish it in a top journal.  Let's ask: why would such a paper deserve to be published there?  Because of the implications of the new result?  If so, show them.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks again, your comments are quite enlightening. To understand your point of view better, I'd appreciate knowing your take on two rather mundane things: i) in your view, the *Advances* is just a reputable or a top journal? ii) I thought that quite a number of better universities (and even the universities seeing themselves as such :( ) essentially require publications in top journals for promotion to the full professor in math, am I wrong on that count?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: If you don't mind, instead of moving to chat we can continue the discussion in my blog post with the snapshot of our part of the above discussion: https://justwonderweb.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/top-journals-and-all-that/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end, the significance of a scientific advance is determined not by how complicated it is or how much hard work was put in, but by comparison with what was known / possible before.

It sounds to me like you need to have a much clearer and stronger comparison with the prior state of the art, particularly emphasizing *why* the new result makes a difference to larger or deeper issues.  Depending on the nature of your work, this might mean anything from a little improvement on the prior work section to introducing new sections with explicit comparisons.

For example, if you were able to mathematically compute the Nash equilibrium for preference of donuts vs. muffins, that's a nifty little result, but it might seem obvious or insignificant.  If you can explain that this was something impossible with prior methods, because nobody had previously been able to deal with the breakfast uncertainty principle, then that is surprising and interesting.  If you can show that your result accurately predicts sales in major chain stores, then that is also surprising and interesting.  In either case, you are showing how your result has implications outside of just being a result.

Now, you could probably also make your work appear harder and more significant by obfuscating the mathematics, and that might "work" for purposes of getting this paper accepted.  I personally, however, consider that to be scientifically dishonest, and would strongly recommend against that.  Remember, that your colleagues are not stupid, and sooner or later, people will realize that you are fluffing up your results, to your detriment.

Comment: *"In the end, the significance of a scientific advance is determined not by how complicated it is or how much hard work was put in, but by comparison with what was known / possible before."* I wish this was an universally accepted fact, but it is not.

Comment: (there are still plenty of people that state that it ain't science if it ain't complicated - and yes, I am saying "complicated" instead of "complex" on purpose ... this is a huge pet peeve of mine)

Comment: @xLeitix I absolutely agree with you, and I think it's an ongoing frustration for many of us.  Scientists are, after all, human.  I do think, though, that in the long term, significance does tend to sort out.

Comment: The reviewers agree that the results themselves are new, important, and were not known before, but they claim that the *techniques* we used are not new. In other words, although no one asked this question before, anyone asking this question would come up with the same answers easily.